# How to set image darkly without background option?

Tags: android

Is There any solution to set image darkly?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/terminalImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I wrote like this, so I can't use background anymore. Is there any option or solution to set background image darkly?

Comment: darkly means what.? you want gradient.?

Comment: @SardarKhan I want to make background darkly.

Comment: then you should have dark image.for the background..

Comment: you can use LayerDrawable.

Comment: @SunSpike check my answer.

Comment: I guess placing view with background color #55000000 in front of your image will be simplest (but dirty, yes) solution for you. Modifying first 2 numbers you can change transparency.

Comment: @NorthernPoet, not really: the simplest way is just to use `Drawable#setColorFilter` method with `LightingColorFilter` parameter (or even easier `Drawable#setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)`)

Answer (score 0):

Add backgdround tint which will add color upon the Existing background.

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add Gradient on Image .
Check this Post[[How to put black transparent on image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061901/how-to-put-black-transparent-on-image-in-android)

Or You can try this post .
[Alpha-gradient on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345824/alpha-gradient-on-android)

you can check the opacity from here.
[How to make a background 20% transparent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-20-transparent-on-android)

For do it Programmaitcally

```
private Bitmap darkenBitMap(Bitmap bm) {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
    //ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF , 0x00222222); // lighten
    ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0xFF7F7F7F, 0x00000000);    // darken
    p.setColorFilter(filter);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, new Matrix(), p);

    return bm;
}
```